# Firefox doesn't resize SVG until window is resized

Tags: firefox, svg

I have an SVG that is set in a data attribute of a canvas element. It's height and width is supposed to be dependent on its container so that it can be responsive. It works fine everywhere except in Firefox. What happens is that when the page first loads, the SVG is displayed at its original size which is much smaller than the container. However, when I resize the window, the SVG will then enlarge to fill up the container as it's supposed to.

The page is here http://bit.ly/VPTJIX and the SVG is the transparent heart on the left

And here's the code from the svg tag.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 208 178" width="208" height="178">
```

I could resize the vector itself and resave the SVG file so that it will be the correct size when the page loads, but I plan on using the same SVG in the site navigation and it will need to be much smaller than it already is.

Comment: It's a known bug with external stylesheets futzing resizing. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=755187

Comment: Ugh, should have figured it had something to do with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has just been fixed by [bug 1063073](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1063073). The fix will be included in Firefox 34.